# Button need to be click twice to fire an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I have a simple ASP.NET Button inside of iFrame, for strange reason i have to click it twice in order to fire an event.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveComment" runat="server" Text="Add Comment" 
            CssClass="button"
            OnClick="btnSaveComment_Click"
            ValidationGroup="add" />

protected void btnSaveComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     AddComment();
}
```

Comment: Is not perhaps because you need to be within the correct IFrame first before you can click that button.

Comment: Similar question with informative answers [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297217/asp-net-c-need-to-press-a-button-twice-to-make-something-happen

Comment: @AndroidHustle: Just for info: In comments, you need to use the inline syntax for hyperlinks. The code for your example should be: `[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297217/asp-net-c-need-to-press-a-button-twice-to-make-something-happen)`, which is shown like this: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297217/asp-net-c-need-to-press-a-button-twice-to-make-something-happen)

Comment: @awe ahh, great! Your version makes it look a lot better! =)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that when you initially click an area above the button you're giving focus to the `iframe` (that is to say, the page within it), and on the second click the mouse can interact with the button.

On the other hand, if the page seems to be posting back but not actually doing anything until the second click, then it might well be related to the page lifecycle, as suggested in an answer comments by @AndroidHustle.

Edit:

To test the theory of whether or not the frame is focused, try giving it focus via script. Something like the following might help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("iFrameId").focus();
</script>
```

Comment: You could use Javascript/jQuery to give focus to the `iframe`, perhaps.

Comment: I fixed by removing button OnClick event from aspx page and created one OnPageLoad method

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is how I solved it:

```
        $("#MainContent_Button1").hover(function (event) {
            $("#MainContent_Button1").click()
        });
```

Now it only takes 1 click, and the button functions like it's supposed to.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save Payment Plan" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```