# YUI calendar not updating after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, postback, yui

I have an ASP.NET (c#) web page containing a YUI calendar. I can select a date and click my book button which inserts that date into a database through c# code behind. However, the calendar does not highlight that day as booked even though the database does a post back. When I refresh the whole page in my browser however, the day appears booked (I have setup the calendar to highlight booked dates). It does this by selecting the dates from the database table I am using.

Is there an easy way to enable the calendar to display the day as highlighted straight away after the book button's post back is complete? Apologies if there is not enough detail in this post!

Thanks

---Edit---
The answer from this question helped me solve this issue: [ASP.NET C#, need to press a button twice to make something happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297217/asp-net-c-need-to-press-a-button-twice-to-make-something-happen)

Basically, I took the code that selected from my database the dates to be highlighted out of the page_load and created another private void and pasted the code in there. I then called this in the code of each of my button onclick events and in my page_load added this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PrivateVoidName();
    }
```

This solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the YUI documentation but yes, you can do that you'll just have to write some javascript to manipulate the calendar live upon post.   You have to think about whether you want to do it optimistically, before verifying that it is saved in the database, or waiting until you have confirmation that it was saved, and then editing the javascript objects.  There is probably an API to the YUI calendar that is like addEvent or something, and you have to actively call it if the calendar has already been loaded.  Even if there isn't a call like that, you could edit the js and make it possible.  If it is too hard, try FullCalendar instead - it's awesome.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have since solved the issue. I posted what I did in my original post. Thanks for the reply.