# Must click a button twice to fire an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a data grid that is created dynamically to display information retrieved from a database. The data grid consists of multiple bound columns and two button columns for each row, a view and a delete button.

Clicking either button calls the Page_Load() method with Page.IsPostBack as false.

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {           
        this.bindForm(); // Populates drop down lists that the user can select     
        setAccess(false); // Sets access for the page 

        // Stuff commented out to avoid confusion                   
    }
    else
    {
        bindDynamicGrids(); // Create the data grid(s) and populate them           
    }
```

So when I first click the button the above code gets called with IsPostBack false, and the dynamic grids get bound. But, the button click event does not fire. When I click the button a second time, Page_Load is called with IsPostBack false, and after executing bindDynamicGrids() the button click event is fired. I cannot understand the difference between the first and second click.

I have read a few threads;

[ASP.NET C#, need to press a button twice to make something happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297217/asp-net-c-need-to-press-a-button-twice-to-make-something-happen)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1783694.aspx?ASP+NET+Button+needs+to+be+clicked+twice

To attempt to understand the issue, but I must be missing something. From what I am gathering from the second link, a session variable may be getting set in the click event, which is also being set in Page_Load, and this is all an issue with ordering. If that is the case I am not seeing where it is happening.

When it is not a post back the bindForm() method is called, which populates all drop down lists. The edit click event populates those drop downs with the values from the row, but the click event is always a post back and the form has already been bound.

I have also considered having a script automatically double click one of the buttons anytime the user single clicks, but I have not been able to find an "OnClick" property for the column button. Any help that could be provided would be phenomenal.

Comment: Please post the code for the two methods: `bindForm()` and `bindDynamicGrids()`.

Comment: I believe any control created dynamically or on the fly does not register events immediately, you must subscribe to them?  I remember doing something similiar from a while back and dynamic controls in asp.net webforms causes issues.

Comment: Add items and events during `Page_Init` instead.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I have added the two pieces of code that you asked for.

Comment: @Walther So instead of adding events when the grid is created I should be adding them in Page_init? What if the dynamic grid has not been created at that point (which I suppose should never happen if Page_init is after Page_Load).

Comment: @JonH I am subscribing to the events as I create the data grids. For example; testGrid.EditCommand += new DataGridCommandEventHandler(testValues_ViewEditCommand);

Comment: You create and bind events in Page_Init and then you populate the values in Page_Load.

Comment: @Walther - I'm just not sure how that is possible. BindDynamicGrids() finds unique items, creates tables for those items, populates the table, and binds events. This is all done dynamically depending on the number of items. I would not have access to all of the data grids inside of Page_Init to bind the events.

Comment: is this the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765815/asp-net-button-event-handlers-do-not-fire-on-the-first-click-but-on-the-second?rq=1

Comment: @Spikolynn Yes, that is the exact same issue. Unfortunately, I am using ButtonColumns for the DataGrid, not buttons, so I have no ID property. This is an interesting idea though and I will investigate whether or not I can assign an ID to a button column. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that the button click event happens after the Page_Load event meaning that the filtering does not get applied on the first postback. It has been updated on the second postback and you see the filtering. 
You can try to move the code of your page_load event to OnPreRender so the reload happens after the button click event.

for more information look here: [Button needs to be clicked twice](http://forums.asp.net/t/1783694.aspx?ASP%20NET%20Button%20needs%20to%20be%20clicked%20twice)
 and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297217/asp-net-c-need-to-press-a-button-twice-to-make-something-happen)

Comment: I still do understand why this is the problem. The sequence of events is the same in both situations. It calls Page_Load and calls bindDynamicGrids(). So even after clicking the edit button the second time the same bindDynamicGrids() is getting executed again, but for some reason it picks up the click the second time.

Comment: hey, i saw it somewhere but i didn't check it out that the: IsPostBack =true suppose to influence somehow... i really not sure about it but maybe it can help. please update me if so.